# "She is starting to understand" vs "She is understanding"

Tags: meaning, present-continuous

**Do the two sentences mean the same thing?**

> (1) She is understanding more and more about physics everyday.
>
> (2) She is starting to understand more and more about physics everyday.

Comment: No (for the reason Victor gives)   "She understands more about physics everyday" is how I'd put it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "*mean*" :-)  There is a difference, I'll try to explain.

Sentence (1) says that her understanding [of physics] is *gradually increasing*.  Nothing about where she is in the process.

Sentence (2) says that she is *at the beginning* of understanding [physics], or that she has *recently returned to studying*, or she *has made a breakthrough* which allowed her understanding to progress [again].

Comment: This is true so long as the two sentences are analyzed in a vacuum. In a more practical application, though, Sentence 1 can mean the same as Sentence 2 with a little surrounding context. _Leslie signed up for her first physics class two weeks ago. She is understanding more and more about physics everyday._ (This is not a criticism of your answer, but it highlights the dangers of an O.P. asking, "Do these sentences mean the same thing?" The answer often depends on where and how the sentences are used.)

Comment: Right. See the first two words of my answer. :-)